# Проверить правильность расстановки скобок

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Совсем не могу понять как это реализовать.Для введённой пользователем с клавиатуры строки (максимальная длина строки — 80 символов) программа должна определить, корректно ли расставлены скобки (круглые, фигурные, квадратные) или нет. Перемешивание скобок (пример: «{[}]») считается некорректным вариантом.

Comment: Идете по строке `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) { char c = str[i]; ... }` смотрите, если  `c` это открывающая скобка, заносите ее в конец массива `if (c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(') p[j++] = c; ...`, если `c` это закрывающая скобка, то проверяете сбалансированность скобок `if (c == '}' || c == ']' || c == ')') { if (j < 1) error, return; switch (c) { case '}' : if (p[j - 1) != '{') error, return; break; case ']': if (p[j - 1]) != '[') error, return; break; ....} --j;}` . После выхода из цикла проверяете, что `j == 0`.  Как-то в таком духе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте стек двигаясь по строке слева на право. Когда приходит открывающая скобка, поместите соответствующую закрывающую скобку в стек. Когда приходит закрывающая скобка сравните её с вершиной стека и удалите вершину. В конце не забудьте проверить что стек пуст:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra parens.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

bool balanced(const std::string &s) {
    std::stack<char> stack;
    for (char c : s) {
        switch (c) {

        case '(': stack.push(')'); break;
        case '[': stack.push(']'); break;
        case '{': stack.push('}'); break;
        case '<': stack.push('>'); break;

        case ')':
        case ']':
        case '}':
        case '>':
            if (stack.empty() || stack.top() != c) {
                return false;
            }
            stack.pop();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return stack.empty();
}

void test(const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << '"' << s << "\" " << (balanced(s) ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
}

int main() {
    test("");
    test("a(b[c]d)e");
    test("a(b[c)d]e");
    test("a(b[c]d");
    test("b[c]d)e");
}
```

> ```
> "" yes
> "a(b[c]d)e" yes
> "a(b[c)d]e" no
> "a(b[c]d" no
> "b[c]d)e" no
> ```

Comment: Не имею ничего против ответа (я и сам это же предлагал), но, ИМХО, зря вы готовую прогу предоставили - человек не понимал как это реализовать, а вы лишили его радости написать код самому. Но это только мое личное мнение.

Comment: Вы правы. Я забрал эту радость себе. Сколько лет программирую, не было шанса написать такую программу. Ничего, вопрос закроют, скорее всего. Впредь буду осмотрительнее. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Решение довольно просто, достаточно внимательнее посмотреть на исходные данные. Эти данные можно представить в качестве операций над стэком: открывающая скобка - push, закрывающая скобка - pop. Единственное что перед pop-ом нужно проверить, что удаляемая скобка имеет такой же тип.